# What does "First rollback" mean in the description of the Clean Up badge?

Tags: support, badges, rollbacks

What does the first [Clean Up badge](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/4/cleanup) mean on mathstack. It defines First roll back. I do not get it.

I was going through badges, and do not quite get what it means. It is a bronze badge.

Comment: Crouch on the floor, and roll back. If you do it successfully the system will be aware and award you with a badge.

Comment: @AsafKaragila -- It didn't work! (I'm ROLLING on the floor laughing)

Comment: @Robin: This just means that you're not doing it right. It's more of a combat roll backwards. Not from side to side out of laughter.

Comment: @Gianluca Why did you roll back to a revision with a less descriptive title? Were you using your new knowledge to earn a badge on meta?

Comment: I'm a Sorry, maybe I did an error

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have edited your question on purpose. If you click [edited...](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/posts/17111/revisions) under the question, revision history opens. In it you can see the first version of your question, with a link "rollback". Clicking it will restore that version of the question.

Try it out.  Incidentally, it should also give you the Cleanup badge here on meta (unless rollback on own posts are excluded.)

#### Notes

1. Yes, Cleanup was awarded.
2. Rollback is available only for posts that you can edit directly (not via suggested edits). At your reputation level this means: own posts, and community wiki posts. With 2000 rep you will have this ability on all posts except locked ones.

Comment: @user147263 I couldn't understand ur answer.